# how can update date from adapter to recyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

when I send new data or update the info, how can to change my recycle view?

I have used a `dapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` , but it's not working...

I tried more method, but it all cannot change my recycler view

in my code

```
 recyclerView =  view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerCoin);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        listCoinDiamondModel = new ArrayList<>();
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        getData();
        adapter = new CoinAdapter(listCoinDiamondModel, getActivity());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

private void sendGift(String postUserID) {
        final String postUserIDD = postUserID;
        final String GiftAmount = this.GiftAmount.getText().toString().trim();
        final String flag = "1";
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_GIFTCOIN,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            String success = jsonObject.getString("success");
                            if (success.equals("1")){
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error" + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                //Log.d("FID", fid);
                params.put("fid", fid);
                params.put("GiftAmount", GiftAmount);
                params.put("flag", flag);
                params.put("postUserID", postUserIDD);
                params.put("uid", getID);
                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }


    private JsonArrayRequest getDataFromServer(int requestCount) {
        //Initializing ProgressBar
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        progressDialog.setMessage("Load...");
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        final String GROUP_LIST = "https://example.com/aaa.php?flag=1&fid="+ getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("fid") +"&page="+requestCount;
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(GROUP_LIST,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        parseData(response);
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No More gift Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

        //Returning the request
        return jsonArrayRequest;
    }

    //This method will get data from the web api
    private void getData() {
        requestQueue.add(getDataFromServer(requestCount));
        requestCount++;
    }

    //This method will parse json data
    private void parseData(JSONArray array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            //Creating the newFeedModel object

            final CoinDiamondModel coinDiamondModel = new CoinDiamondModel();
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                //Getting json
                json = array.getJSONObject(i);

                String TAG_Coin = "Coin";
                String TAG_Diamond = "Diamond";
                String TAG_UserName = "UserName";
                String TAG_UserPhoto = "UserPhoto";
                String TAG_UserID = "UserID";

                //Log.d("NAME111", json.getString(json.getString(TAG_UserName)));
                coinDiamondModel.setCoin(json.getString(TAG_Coin));
                coinDiamondModel.setDiamond(json.getString(TAG_Diamond));
                coinDiamondModel.setGiftFromUserName(json.getString(TAG_UserName));
                coinDiamondModel.setGiftFromUserPhoto(json.getString(TAG_UserPhoto));
                coinDiamondModel.setGiftFromUserID(json.getString(TAG_UserID));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //Adding the newFeedModel object to the list
            listCoinDiamondModel.add(coinDiamondModel);
            //adapter.addTheCoinData(coinDiamondModel);
        }

        //Notifying the adapter that data has been added or changed
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

who knows what's happen and how can solve this?

could you told me how can I do, please?

adapter all code

```
public class CoinAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CoinAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private List<CoinDiamondModel> newcoinDiamondLists;
    private RequestManager glide;
    private Context context;
    SessionManager sessionManager;
    private String getID,memail;

    public CoinAdapter(List<CoinDiamondModel> newcoinDiamondLists, Context context) {
        this.newcoinDiamondLists = newcoinDiamondLists;
        this.glide = Glide.with(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.coinlist, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);

        sessionManager = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
        sessionManager.checkLogin();
        HashMap<String, String> user = sessionManager.getUserDetail();
        getID = user.get(sessionManager.USERID);
        memail = user.get(sessionManager.EMAIL);

        //String gid = getIntent.getStringExtra("xxx");


        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        CoinDiamondModel newCoinDiamondModel = newcoinDiamondLists.get(position);
        imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();

        holder.userName.setText(newCoinDiamondModel.getGiftFromUserName());
        holder.userID.setText(newCoinDiamondModel.getGiftFromUserID());
        holder.coinCount.setText(" x "+newCoinDiamondModel.getCoin());
        glide.load(newCoinDiamondModel.getGiftFromUserPhoto()).into(holder.userPhoto);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return newcoinDiamondLists.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CircleImageView userPhoto;
        TextView userName,userID,coinCount;
        ImageView coinImg;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            userPhoto = (CircleImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.userPhoto);
            userName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.userName);
            coinCount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.coinCount);
            userID = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.userID);
            coinImg = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.coinImg);
        }
    }

    public void addTheCoinData(CoinDiamondModel coinDiamondModel){
        if(coinDiamondModel!=null){
            newcoinDiamondLists.add(coinDiamondModel);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("無資料!");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: update adapter whenever data changes with new data list, again and again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RecyclerView initialization and `notifyDataSetChanged()` is used properly. As your question is not clear enough about the Adapter implementation of the RecyclerView, I can give you several suggestions to check.

1. In `RecyclerView.Adapter` check if `getItemCount()` method is properly overriden with returning the list length (not 0) like below:

> ```
> @Override  
> public int getItemCount() {  
>     return listdata.length;  
> }
> ```

2. In `RecyclerView.Adapter` check if `onCreateViewHolder` method is properly overriden with proper xml layout like below:

> ```
> @Override  
> public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {  
>     LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());  
>     View listItem= layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.coin_xml_layout, parent, false);  
>     ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(listItem);  
>     return viewHolder;  
> }
> ```

3. In `RecyclerView.Adapter` check if `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` class is properly extended
   and linked the UI elements from the xml with the adapter like below:

> ```
> public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {  
>     public TextView coinTextView;  
>     public ViewHolder(View itemView) {  
>         super(itemView);  
>         this.coinTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.coinTextView);    
>     }  
> }
> ```

4. In `RecyclerView.Adapter` check if `onBindViewHolder` method is properly overridden and updated the list component UI properly like below:

> ```
>   @Override  
>   public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {  
>         final MyListData myListData = listdata[position];  
>         holder.cointTextView.setText(listdata[position].getCoin());  
>     }
> ```

5. Debug with a breakpoint and check if the `listCoinDiamondModel.add(coinDiamondModel)` is calling or not and `coinDiamondModel` object is not empty.
6. The RecyclerView is placed properly in the activity xml, like the RecyclerView is Visible, has a decent size to show list elements. As an example:

> ```
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"  
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"  
>     android:scrollbars="vertical"
> ```

Comment: I cannot change listdata.length;

Comment: why? what are the difficulties you are facing?

Answer (score 1):

you can again set the adapter to recycler view after the response of the server

```
   public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    parseData(response);
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    adapter = new CoinAdapter(listCoinDiamondModel, getActivity());
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
```

solution 2:
in your adapter write a function to update you list
and call function in activity

add this function to the adapter

```
    public void updateList(List<CoinDiamondModel> list){
    newcoinDiamondLists = list;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
     }
```

and call a function `updateList` of when you need an update recyclerview

Comment: I have tried this method, but it's still not refreshing recyclerview

Comment: @Stanley please share your adapter and full code activity

Comment: I have add updateList function in the adapter, but I cannot call this function in the fragment....

Answer (score 0):

you can update your adapter list manually like this:(write this function in your adapter)

```
public void updateCoinAdapterList(ArrayList<listCoinDiamondModel> recyclerItemsList) {
        this.recyclerItemsList = recyclerItemsList;
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

you must set your adapter global variable and initialize it in OnCreate or OnResume, and call

```
adapter.updateCoinAdapterList(listCoinDiamondModel);
```

when your list changed

Comment: but I cannot call this function in the fragment

Comment: why not? you can initialize your adapter and call adapter.updateCoinAdapterList(listCoinDiamondModel);

Comment: updateCoinAdapterList and  onResume, add in Fragment or?

Comment: after updating your list in your fragment call this function in your fragment

Comment: I have add updateCoinAdapterList to Adapter, and add public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        adapter.updateCoinAdapterList();
    }  in Fragment , But I cannot call this function. error " cannot resolve method  updateCoinAdapterList()"  error: cannot find symbol
        adapter.updateCoinAdapterList();